# Azure AD OAuth SSO intergration with Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory, adal4j

I am developing a few microservices with Spring Cloud (Eureka, Zuul).

I want to integrate Azure AD OAuth2 SSO into my application. I searched several blogs and articles but failed find any tutorials for Azure AD.

Please advise me how this can done.